# Como ordenar 2 Strings para que siempre salga uno primero que otro Android

Tags: android, android-studio, string, edittext

Estoy intentando realizar una función que reciba 2 `String`, dentro de la misma se debe evaluar que alguno de estos no este vacío y las respectivas validaciones. El fin de esto es generar un nombre de usuario, de manera que la primera letra del nombre siempre este de primera, y el apellido se concatene siempre de segundo. Ejemplo: Carlos Villa, Respuesta: CVilla, esto debe hacerse a penas se inserten valores en el `EditText`, cabe destacar que si no se ha insertado nombre, debe colocarse el apellido igual, y al momento de ingresar el nombre, el primer caracter de este debe estar de primero, esto es lo que he he intentado:

```
            name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(name!=null) {
                    if (count >= 2) {
                        setValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

            surname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(surname!=null) {
                    if (count >= 2) {
                        setValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Acá intento captar el momento en que cambia cada `Editext` exactamente.

Ahora este es el método que intento implementar para lograr que se ordenen de la forma que deseo:

```
@Override
    public void setValue() {
        String value = GenereteOrderUsername(view.getName(),view.getSurName());
        view.setValue(value);
    }

    public static String GenereteOrderUsername(String name, String surname){
            String letter = null;
            String username = null;
            if (name == null || name.isEmpty()){
                return "";
            } else {
                letter = name.substring(0,1);
            }

            if (surname == null || surname.isEmpty()){
                return "";
            } else {
                if(name == null){
                    return "";
                }
                username = letter+surname;
            }

            return username;
        }
```

La respuesta de esto es que si coloco el apellido, no aparece nada en el nombre de usuario hasta que coloco el nombre, existe alguna mejor manera de hacer esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: pero en que momento llamas le metodo para ordenarlos?  el nombre y le apellido se ingresan en el mismo editext o por separado?

Comment: por separado, debe ser así, de manera que cada vez que se ingrese alguno de ellos se realice la acción correspondiente, si se coloca el nombre, solo se marca la primera letra del mismo, si se coloca el apellido, este debe aparecer completamente en el otro campo, pero, si se ingresa el nombre ya teniendo valor el apellido, el primer caracter del nombre debe tomar el primer lugar de la cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Creeria  que lo que necesitas son dos TextWacher que formen tu usuario:

```
 nombre = findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    apellido = findViewById(R.id.apellido);
    usuario = findViewById(R.id.usuario);


    nombre.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {M
            String nombreTxt = nombre.getText().toString().trim();
            String apellidoTxt = apellido.getText().toString().trim();
          if (nombreTxt.length()>0){
              usuario.setText(nombreTxt.charAt(0)+apellidoTxt);
          }else{
              usuario.setText(apellidoTxt);
          }

        }
    });
    apellido.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            String nombreTxt = nombre.getText().toString().trim();
            String apellidoTxt = apellido.getText().toString().trim();
            if (nombreTxt.length()>0){
                usuario.setText(nombreTxt.charAt(0)+apellidoTxt);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Eso es lo que estoy haciendo, el caso es que necesito que si el apellido se introduce antes que el nombre, independientemente de lo que sea, este se coloque de primero, es decir, busco un método de ordenamiento efectivo